# The vector r points from $P'(x',y',z')$ to $P(x,y,z)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, differentiation

For some reason this question is giving me a hard time :(

The vector $r$ points from $P'(x',y',z')$ to $P(x,y,z)$.

(a) Show that if $P$ is fixed and $P'$ is allowed to move, then $\nabla'(\frac{1}{r})=\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}$

(b) (a) Show that if $P'$ is fixed and $P$ is allowed to move, then $\nabla(\frac{1}{r})=-\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}$

I don't really understand the notation $\nabla'(\frac{1}{r})$ What is the prime? what exactly am I applying the gradient operator to? and how can I show this and answer the question proposed?

Answer (score 1):

The prime on ∇′ means that you're differentiating with respect to the primed coodinates (x',y',z') treating (x,y,z) as constants. Presumably, r is the *magnitude* of the vector that points from P' to P-- this is just a simple difference of vectors. Good luck!